# Column selection in multiple columns by using single click?

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, multiple-columns, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2012

My report look like below

```
Region1 Region2 Region3 Region4 Region5 state1 state2 state3 state4 state5
```

I have created column selection parameter and Region value  0
                                              State  value 1

How I need to make changes if I select Region only regions 1 to 5 are displayed, or if I select State only states 1 to 5 are displayed?

Can you please help me guys I have been stuck for 3 days. I tried of selecting using single column selection by using below

```
expression =iif(instr(Join(Parameters!ColumnSelect.Value,","),"01")>0,false,true)
```

But i am unable select 5 columns at a time.

Answer (score 2):

I think your expression should be:

```
= Not(Join(Parameters!ColumnSelect.Value,",").Contains("0"))
```

I would be applying that as the Column Hidden Expression for the Region columns.  A similar expression (with the "0" changed to "1") should work for the State columns.

Answer (score 1):

Set the Hidden Condition of each column individually. Make sure you are selecting the columns under Column Groups in the Advanced Mode of the Grouping Window:

[image: Advanced Mode]

Region Columns Hidden Condition:

```
=Join(Parameters!ColumnSelect.Value,",") not like '*0*'
```

State Columns Hidden Condition:

```
=Join(Parameters!ColumnSelect.Value,",") not like '*1*'
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using below expression

```
=IIF(instr(Join(Parameters!ColumnsSelect.value,", "),"0")=0,True,False)
=IIF(instr(Join(Parameters!ColumnsSelect.value,", "),"1")=0,True,False)
```